# I get a compilation error when using generics

Tags: java, generics

i write the following code:

```
 public void test() {
  Callable<?> myCall = new Callable() {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return doDomething();
    }
};


Callable<?> myCall2 = new Callable() {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return doDomething2();
    }
};

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

List<Future<?>> futuresList = executor.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<?>>) getList());

String result1 = futuresList.get(0).get();

String result2 = futuresList.get(0).get();

...
...

}

private List<Callable<?>> getList() {
    .. create callables with wildcard and return them
}
```

i get the following compilation error: The method invokeAll(Collection>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Collection>).

EDIT
i added a method getList because i want this to use generics and not String.
I want to understand why it doesnt compile. and in my real program it is a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand when you need wildcards in generics. In your example, you don't need them at all. You only need them when you don't know the type of some generic object. In your example, you want the Callables to return Strings so you should use  as your generic type, like this:

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

  Callable<String> myCall = new Callable<String>(){
    public String call() throws Exception{
      return doDomething();
    }
  };


  Callable<String> myCall2 = new Callable<String>(){
    public String call() throws Exception{
      return doDomething2();
   }
  };

  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  List<Callable<String>> list = Arrays.asList(myCall, myCall2);
  List<Future<String>> futuresList = executor.invokeAll(list);

  String result1 = futuresList.get(0).get();
  String result2 = futuresList.get(1).get();

  executor.shutdown();
}
```

See Sun's / Oracle's [tutorial on generics and wildcards](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

**EDIT:**

- changed `futuresList.get(0)` to `futuresList.get(1)` to get the second result
- added `executor.shutdown()` because people tend to forget this...

**EDIT2:**

Responding to your comment, here is another example. That's one way you could do stuff like this. I want to show how you have to generify all involved method from the caller all the way down inside your Callables or better your `doDomething` methods.

```
public void test() throws Exception {

  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  List<Callable<String>> list = getList();
  List<Future<String>> futuresList = executor.invokeAll(list);

  String result1 = futuresList.get(0).get();
  String result2 = futuresList.get(1).get();

  System.out.println(result1);
  System.out.println(result2);

  executor.shutdown();
}

private <T> List<Callable<T>> getList() {

  Callable<T> myCall = new Callable<T>(){
    public T call() throws Exception{
      return (T) "a"; //doDomething();
    }
  };

  Callable<T> myCall2 = new Callable<T>(){
    public T call() throws Exception{
      return (T) "b"; //doDomething2();
    }
  };

  return Arrays.asList(myCall, myCall2);
}
```

Comment: i edited my question. I know that in this example i can use String. but my real program is more generic. I need to use wildcard.

Comment: I added another example. This example includes a cast, what should not ne neccessary if you do generics all the way. However, I find myself needing a cast every now and then, maybe someone else give a hint how to optimize the example.

Comment: Thanks. do i understand correctly, that we need to use generic here and no wildcard, only because the invokeAll method is written with generic and not wildcard?

Comment: @dan: You have to think of a wildcard type, more as an abstract thing. The receiver may want to express something like "give me some vehicle, I don't care if it's a car or a bus". This may written like "List<? extends vehicle>". The caller has some concrete List, e.g. a List<Car> and can pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cast in the line with `invokeAll()`, and change your unbound wildcards (`?`) with `String`. This doesn't compile, and its possible but hard to explain exactly why, but, since you really intend to operate on `String`, just say so and it works.

Comment: I edited the question. i dont intend to work with string only.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers posted - you should just be parameterising on `String` rather than a wildcard.

If you want to know *why* the wildcards aren't working as you expect, Angelika Langer's excellent Java Generics FAQ has a section on [repeating wildcard declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436807/i-get-a-compilation-error-when-using-generics/6436880#6436880) which covers this (it's the second example).